# Java Converting String to Date resulting one day less even though browser time zone provided

Tags: java, timezone, date-parsing, date

I'm sending date from the Angular app as String to server and converting to java `Date` object to store in the database.

Also sending `timeZoneOffset` from UI to use the client's time zone while converting. (After googling I found this approach to get the proper result based on the user location)

Written the following code to convert:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String inputDate = "04/05/2018"; // This date coming from UI
    int timeZoneOffset = -330; // This offset coming from UI 
                               // (new Date().getTimeZoneOffset())
    getDate(inputDate, timeZoneOffset);
}

public static Date getDate(String inputDate, int timeZoneOffset)
        throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(-timeZoneOffset * 60);
    System.out.println("Default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneOffset);
    System.out.println("Time zone from offset: " + timeZone.getID());
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(inputDate);
    System.out.println("Converted date: " + date);
    return date;
}
```

**Expected output**:

> Default time zone: America/New_York
>       Time zone from offset: GMT+05:30
>       Converted date: Thu April 5 00:00:00 IST 2018

**Actual result in server**:

> Default time zone: America/New_York
>       Time zone from offset: GMT+05:30
>       Converted date: Wed April 4 14:30:00 EDT 2018

Why is the date decreasing to one day even I set the users time zone? I'm new to Date and Time related concepts and I googled a couple of times didn't find answer, could someone please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Answer by Godfrey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49679312/642706) is correct.

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "04/05/2018" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) 
)
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-04-05T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

For storage in your database, use UTC.

When a new day starts in India, the date at UTC is still “yesterday”, so April 4th rather than April 5th. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "04/05/2018" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) 
)
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
)
.toInstant()
```

> 2018-04-04T18:30:00Z

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes entirely

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(-timeZoneOffset * 60);
…
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneOffset);
```

You are mixing the modern classes (`ZoneOffset`) with the troublesome legacy classes (`TimeZone`). **Do not mix the modern classes with the legacy classes.** Forget all about the old classes including `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. The *java.time* classes are designed to entirely supplant the legacy classes.

Instead of `TimeZone`, use `ZoneId` (and `ZoneOffset`).

### `LocalDate`

Parse your input string as a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "04/05/2018" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

### Offset versus Time Zone

> int timeZoneOffset = -330;

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is *not* a time zone. An offset is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds of displacement from UTC. Your choice of variable name indicates possible confusion on this point.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( -3 , 30 ) ;
```

A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region. So a time zone is always preferable to an offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  // India time zone. Currently uses offset of +05:30 (five and a half hours ahead of UTC).
```

#### First moment of the day

You seem to be aiming for the first moment of that date in that zone. Let java.time determine that first-moment-of-the-day. Do not assume that time is 00:00:00. In some zones on some dates, the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine the first moment of the day on this date in this zone. Not always 00:00:00.
```

As an example of why you should be using time zones rather than mere offset-from-UTC, look at your example data of `-330` which I might easily misinterpret to be three and a half hours behind UTC. This offset is currently only used in the zone `America/St_Johns`, and only used there for part of the year. So if you applied an offset of -03:30 to a date in the wrong part of the year, your results would be invalid yet go undetected.

### Using offset (not recommended)

But your example lacks time zone, so let’s go with offset-from-UTC rather than zone.

Your use of an `int` integer number to represent an offset-from-UTC is a poor choice of types. First of all, it is ambiguous. That `-330` might be interpreted to be a clumsy attempt at `-03:30` offset of three and a half hours behind schedule. Secondly, it makes parsing trickier than need be. Thirdly, as a number of minutes, it ignores the possibility of an offset with seconds. Fourthly, you use a negative number for an offset *ahead* of UTC (apparently) despite common usage and standard usage being the opposite. Lastly, it ignores the clear standard set by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for representing offsets as text: `±HH:MM:SS` (and variations). By the way, the padding zero is optional in the standard, but I recommend always including because various libraries and protocols expect it.

Your intent appears to be a number of minutes intended by the integer number.

```
long seconds =( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( - 330 ) * -1 );  // Multiply by negative one to flip the sign to standard ISO 8601 usage, where `+` means “ahead* of UTC and `-` means *behind* UTC.
```

> seconds: 19800

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds( ( int ) seconds );
```

> offset.toString(): +05:30

Last step: get the first moment of the day in this offset. Caveat: We do not know for certain if this offset is valid on this date, as we lack a time zone.

Convert from the returned `ZonedDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime`. As discussed above, determining first moment of day should always be done with a time zone, and thereby get a `ZonedDateTime`. We are violating that sensible practice to use an offset, but using the returned `ZonedDateTime` object would be misleading as ours would lack a true time zone, and have only a mere offset. So the `OffsetDateTime` class makes our intentions clear and our code more self-documenting.

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = ld.atStartOfDay( offset ).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Again, this approach using offset is *not* recommending, as you should be instead gathering a time zone *name* from the user as input rather than an offset.

## UTC

Generally best to store moments in UTC.

Extract a `Instant` from your `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` to get the same moment as UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> 2018-04-04T18:30:00Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great explanation. It's helpful for me. LocalDate is worked for me as I don't need time at all and need to store only user provided date value. Thank you very much for your time for giving such explanation Basil Bourque. Definitely I will look into java.time framework for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's not decreasing by one day, it is decreasing by 11.5 hours.  That happens to be the time difference between GMT+05:30 and "America/New_York", which is GMT-04:30 or GMT-05:30 (depending on time of year).

GMT+05:30 is somewhere in India, I think, since that is about the only place to use a 30 minute offset rather than a whole hour. When it is April 5th in India, it is still April 4th in New York.

The problem may be you aren't getting a time from the client, so it will assume midnight. If you are doing time zone conversion, it is best to include the actual time.

Comment: I agree, but what is the use of setting time zone to dateFormat before parsing the string date. I'm expecting April 5th Midnight from the result because I already set the timezone to GMT+5:30. Even If I add time It still decrese the 11:30 hrs right?

Comment: yes, you are PARSING the date as if it is in GMT+5:30, but the system timezone is New York. If the input time zone and output time zones are the same, you don't need to do any timezone conversion.

Comment: Ok. Your explanation is helpful for me. Thank you Garr Godfrey.